# Does Netezza support the Cursor declaration like in PL/SQL

Tags: netezza, cursors

Does Netezza support the Cursor declaration like in PL/SQL?
I believe, FOR Loops does support a select query. But do we have any explicit way to define a cursor in Netezza?

Answer (score 0):

Netezza has a construct called RECORDS.  It has limited per-record capabilities.   Documentation is available here.
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/netezza?topic=grammar-records